# Ajax Accordion Loses Current Pane

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

I'm using an Ajax Accordion with several panes. On a postback the currently opened pane is always reset back to the first pane.

Is there any way around this problem?

Thanks

Rob.

Comment: Hi, Are you referring Ajax post-back or browser refresh?

Comment: Could you post some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked-around the problem by passing the current pane index in the query string then setting the current pane back to the index in the Page_Load event of the target page.

Thanks,

Rob.

Comment: could u please provide some code snippet i have same problem ...please help me rob...

Answer (score 0):

i do solve this by use link with `Query String` like this below

```
url="~/Opportunity/Indent.aspx?index=1" // replace 1 with your desired index
```

and in page load event write something like this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

        Dim selectedindex As String = Request.QueryString("index")
        UserAccordion.SelectedIndex = selectedindex



    End Sub
```