# Ajax accordion Control: On Selecting links in pane automatically lost focus from current pane

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

[image]

i doesn't know is it very easy question or hard but today i come across this problem.

I have `Ajax Accordion` control on my Master page with Three `Panes`[Gray colored Square area with **Master ST ERP** text is content page ].

Now, My problem is whenever i selecting link represent as Tree in **User Detail** pane it collapses itself and automatically **ST-ERP Modules** Pane is opens.
which make me frustrate...
what should be the problem friends...
Same kind of question on SO but can't helps me: [Ajax Accordion Loses Current Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574335/ajax-accordion-loses-current-pane)

**This is my Code snippet:**

```
<ajax:Accordion ID="UserAccordion" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
                            FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250"
                            FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None" 
                            Width="220px">
                            <Panes>
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1"  runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">ST-ERP Modules</a></Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="UserReg" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="treeMainMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                                                NodeIndent="10" Width="150px" OnTreeNodeDataBound="treeMainMenu_TreeNodeDataBound">
                                                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False"></ParentNodeStyle>
                                                <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="#447BD4" Font-Underline="True"></HoverNodeStyle>
                                                <SelectedNodeStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#DD5555" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></SelectedNodeStyle>
                                                <NodeStyle NodeSpacing="0px" HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#447BD4" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana"></NodeStyle>
                                            </asp:TreeView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">User Detail</a></Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="TreeView1" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2" NodeIndent="10"
                                                Width="150px">
                                                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False"></ParentNodeStyle>
                                                <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="white" Font-Underline="True"></HoverNodeStyle>
                                                <SelectedNodeStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#DD5555" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></SelectedNodeStyle>
                                                <NodeStyle NodeSpacing="0px" HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="White" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana"></NodeStyle>
                                            </asp:TreeView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">Job Details</a>
                                    </Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                                            ddddddddddddd</asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                            </Panes>
                        </ajax:Accordion>
```