# Asp.net Ajax Accordion: keep open ajax accordion pan after post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

I have used `Ajax Accordion` control on my `Master Page` on `Page_Load` event i want to set `SelectedIndex` property of `Accordion` control which i have set inside java script.

My problme is each time in `Page_Load` event the value of **HiddenField1.Value = " "** that is nothing. i am not getting the value of hidden field which i have set in java script instead i get just notthing or empty string.

Below is hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="Server"  />
```

**NOTE:(1)** I have used `HiddenField` to complete my task.
**(2)** I am doing this because [Ajax Accordion Loses Current Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574335/ajax-accordion-loses-current-pane?lq=1) after post back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad()
         {
            $find('<%= UserAccordion.ClientID %>' + '_AccordionExtender').add_selectedIndexChanged(onAccordionPaneChanged); 
        }

       function onAccordionPaneChanged(sender, eventArgs) 
         { 
           var selPane = sender.get_SelectedIndex();
           document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = selPane;
           //alert("SelectedIndex:" + selPane  ); This message fires nicely so i have confirmed that this event work
         }
    </script>
```

Following is my back end code in `.vb` file

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If HiddenField1.Value = "" Then
        Else

            UserAccordion.SelectedIndex = HiddenField1.Value

        End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Code of Accordion Control.

```
<ajax:Accordion ID="UserAccordion" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
                            FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250"
                            FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None"  
                            Width="220px" >
                            <Panes >
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1"  runat="server" >
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">ST-ERP Modules</a></Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="UserReg" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="treeMainMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                                                NodeIndent="10" Width="150px" OnTreeNodeDataBound="treeMainMenu_TreeNodeDataBound">
                                                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False"></ParentNodeStyle>
                                                <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="#447BD4" Font-Underline="True"></HoverNodeStyle>
                                                <SelectedNodeStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#DD5555" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></SelectedNodeStyle>
                                                <NodeStyle NodeSpacing="0px" HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#447BD4" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana"></NodeStyle>
                                            </asp:TreeView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2" runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">User Detail</a></Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                                            <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="TreeView1" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2" NodeIndent="10"
                                                Width="150px">
                                                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False"></ParentNodeStyle>
                                                <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="white" Font-Underline="True"></HoverNodeStyle>
                                                <SelectedNodeStyle HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="#DD5555" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True"></SelectedNodeStyle>
                                                <NodeStyle NodeSpacing="0px" HorizontalPadding="0px" ForeColor="White" VerticalPadding="0px"
                                                    Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Verdana"></NodeStyle>
                                            </asp:TreeView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                                <ajax:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane3" runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        <a href="#" class="href">Job Details</a>
                                    </Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                                            ddddddddddddd</asp:Panel>
                                    </Content>
                                </ajax:AccordionPane>
                            </Panes>
                        </ajax:Accordion>
```

Comment: Actually the Accordion control holds state on postback. Show your markup and code before you had apply your workaround. Also you may  check value of `UserAccordion_AccordionExtender_ClientState` hidden field with Fiddler or firebug sent to server on postback.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy see i have update my question and may be i have problem because i m using accordion with TreeView inside pane and treeview bounded to `web.sitemap` files   thank you so much for replying

Comment: I have solved this problem see my answer on [this post][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574335/ajax-accordion-loses-current-pane?lq=1


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574335/ajax-accordion-loses-current-pane?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear Node's NavigateUrl property in both treeview's `TreeNodeDataBound` event handlers:

```
protected void treView_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.NavigateUrl = null;
}
```

Comment: ya...it works but problem is each node of treeview have a link which will open content page...if i set **e.node.navigateUrl=null** navigation URL doesn't works..and which is must requires...thank you so much for replying

Comment: handle `SelectedNodeChanged` event and open referenced page manually

Comment: ya this works fine...but is there any way to solve this problem by JABASCRIT .....thank you so much for replying

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem see my answer on this post
[Ajax Accordion Loses Current Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574335/ajax-accordion-loses-current-pane?lq=1)

**Below if link broken:**

i do solve this by use link with `Query String` like this below

```
url="~/Opportunity/Indent.aspx?index=1" // replace 1 with your desired index
```

and in page load event write something like this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

        Dim selectedindex As String = Request.QueryString("index")
        UserAccordion.SelectedIndex = selectedindex



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the session variable (i.e. Accordion.SelectedIndex = Session("AccordionIndex") but QueryString would work the same as well (unless you want to suppress the index from the URL, then session state would work better)